# VB.NET Webbrowser 1 navigate to textbox

Tags: vb.net

I need to to browse to JUST the first line but instead it just puts everything in

my code:

```
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://youtube.com/" + gathered.TextBox1.Text)
```

So like if textbox1 have these people

joe

austin

bob.

cody

it will do youtube.com/joeaustinbobcody

and i only want it to do youtube.com/joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use VB linefeed as a delimiter between the names, and then split the string into a string array. Then just use the first name:

```
Dim l() As String = gathered.TextBox1.Text.split(CChar(vbLf))
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://youtube.com/" + l.First)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I know what you want to do, I can help you with this:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.youtube.com" & "/" & TextBox1.Text)
```

or:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.youtube.com/" & TextBox1.Text)
```